# Handling empty cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, accounting

How do I handle empty cell values in a DataGridView where I have 3 columns(Account Title, Debit, Credit), the first column the user chooses an account, then inputs either the Debit or Credit column, thus leaving an empty cell in every row. I have 3 tables involved for a single entry.

```
create table Debit (debit_id, amount, **acct_id, entry_id);
create table Credit (credit_id, amount, **acct_id, entry_id);
create table Entry (entry_id, date);
```

Basically I want it to look like [this](http://www.edisonsattic.com/articles/images/QBTrust1/2.gif). What I've done so far is joined those 3 tables

```
SELECT  Entry.entry_id, Entry.Date, Debit.acct_id, Debit.amount, 
Credit.acct_id, Credit.amount FROM Entry FULL OUTER JOIN Debit
ON Entry.entry_id = Debit.entry_id FULL OUTER JOIN Credit
ON Entry.entry_id = Credit.entry_id
```

Having 6 columns in the DataGridView. I still haven't thought of a query to show only 3 columns where the Debit and Credit accounts are in one column and the amount on their appropriate column, and if there was how does it handle the empty cells on the column for Debit and Credit What I've done works but usability wise it's not good.

Can you suggest of ways for me to do this.

** Account table

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my answer, but in my experience `DataGridView`s are a bit picky about binding to the object type they get from a variable. I'm assuming you're using some sort of SqlReader or perhaps a DataTable to get the results from this SQL Query. The problem is that they will return a type of `Decimal` (hopefully if it's money). Whereas the database actually stores it as a `Nullable(of Decimal)`. If you bind the grid to data types that match your intent, you will see better results.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing a union would fix your problem.  The following query will combine both sets of results into a single resultset:

select e.entry_id, e.Date, d.acct_id, d.amount from Entry as e join Debit as d on e.entry_id=d.entry_id

union all

select e.entry_id, e.Date, c.acct_id, c.amount from Entry as e join Credit as c on e.entry_id=c.entry_id

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring that (a) you are using data binding and (b) this is for the user to input data.
If it *is* for input then I would forgo the data binding and populate /read back from the grid in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `DataGridView` I would recommend going with a more Object Oriented approach, rather than passing the results of a SQL query straight through. How are you even pushing the updates back with this method anyway?

Here's an example. I know it's in VB.Net, but it should still make sense.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim entries As List(Of AccountEntry) = RetrieveEntries()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = entries

    End Sub

    Public Class AccountEntry
        Public Property Id As Integer
        Public Property Debit As Nullable(Of Decimal)
        Public Property Credit As Nullable(Of Decimal)
        Public Property EntryDate As DateTime
    End Class

    Public Function RetrieveEntries() As List(Of AccountEntry)
        Dim returnEntries As List(Of AccountEntry) = Nothing
        ' Do your database stuff here to retrieve a list of AccountEntry'
        Return returnEntries
    End Function

End Class
```